# How to run Kibana 4.4.1 on IBM Bluemix PaaS

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry, kibana-4, elasticsearch-2.0

I am trying to run Kibana 4.4.1 on an IBM Bluemix PaaS as a nodejs application. In my implementation, i use cloudfoundry to connect to the PaaS cloud.

I was able to run Kibana 4.1.1 on PaaS using the following steps

```
> Download Kibana from here to your personal desktop:
> https://download.elastic.co/kibana/kibana/kibana-4.1.1-windows.zip
> Extract the files using WinZip and navigate to /src/config/index.js
> Modify the following line from:
> // Set defaults for config file stuff
> kibana.port = kibana.port || 5601;
> To the following:
> kibana.port = process.env.PORT || 5601;

> Once the change has been made save the file.

> Navigate to the folder /src/ and create a new file called manifest.yml. The contents of this file should be the following:

> ---
> applications:
>  - name: %name%
>    host: %name%
>    memory: %memory%
>    domain: xyz.hfhf.mybluemix.net
>    instances: 1
>    command: node ./bin/kibana.js
>    env:
>      NODE_ENV: production
>      CONFIG_PATH: ./config/kibana.yml

> This file will tell Blue Mix how to run this application once uploaded. The %name% should be the same as the application name within Blue Mix. For %memory% use an increment of 128M, 256M, 512M.

> Navigate to the folder /src/config/ and open the file kibana.yml. Add the following lines to the end of the file:

> bundled_plugin_ids:
>  - plugins/dashboard/index
>  - plugins/discover/index
>  - plugins/doc/index
>  - plugins/kibana/index
>  - plugins/markdown_vis/index
>  - plugins/metric_vis/index
>  - plugins/settings/index
>  - plugins/table_vis/index
>  - plugins/vis_types/index
>  - plugins/visualize/index

> In the same file we need to update the variable “elasticsearch_url” to point to the virtual machine’s IP:

> elasticsearch_url: "http://<Virtual Machine IP>:9200"

> Save the file when finished.

> Download the Cloud Foundary Command Line Interface (CF CLI) here:

> https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cli/releases

> Once CF CLI has been installed follow the steps from the webpage we need to connect to Blue Mix. Open up command prompt on your computer by navigating to Start -> Run and typing in “CMD”:

>  

> To connect to Blue Mix use the command “cf api https://api.ng.bluemix.net”:
>  

> Log in to Blue Mix “cf login –u user_name –o org_name –s space_name”:
>  

> User_name is your login for Blue Mix
> Org_name is the organization that will house the application(s)
> Space_name is the folder which the application will be stored

> To upload the application use the command cf push in the following syntax “cf push appname –m 512m”
>  

> When pushing the application make sure the directory is the /src/ folder of kibana.
```

but these steps dont work for Kibana 4.4.1 as the directory structure is completely different. I tried to push Kibana to PaaS by moving to the src folder and typing the `cf push` command, but it fails to upload.

Has anyone tried to do this?

**Error Stacktrace**

```
2016-03-15T11:36:38.12-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        character-parser@1.2.1 /tmp/staged/app/node_modules/jade/node_modules/character-parser
2016-03-15T11:36:38.12-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        clean-css@3.4.10 /tmp/staged/app/node_modules/jade/node_modules/clean-css
2016-03-15T11:36:38.12-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        graceful-readlink@1.0.1 /tmp/staged/app/node_modules/jade/node_modules/clean-css/node_modules/commander/node_modules/graceful-readlink
2016-03-15T11:36:38.13-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        source-map@0.4.4 /tmp/staged/app/node_modules/jade/node_modules/clean-css/node_modules/source-map
2016-03-15T11:36:38.13-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        amdefine@1.0.0 /tmp/staged/app/node_modules/jade/node_modules/clean-css/node_modules/source-map/node_modules/amdefine
2016-03-15T11:36:38.13-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        commander@2.6.0 /tmp/staged/app/node_modules/jade/node_modules/commander
2016-03-15T11:36:38.13-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        constantinople@3.0.2 /tmp/staged/app/node_modules/jade/node_modules/constantinople
2016-03-15T11:36:38.13-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        acorn@2.7.0 /tmp/staged/app/node_modules/jade/node_modules/constantinople/node_modules/acorn
2016-03-15T11:36:38.13-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        promise@6.1.0 /tmp/staged/app/node_modules/jade/node_modules/jstransformer/node_modules/promise
2016-03-15T11:36:38.13-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        transformers@2.1.0 /tmp/staged/app/node_modules/jade/node_modules/transformers
2016-03-15T11:36:38.13-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        css-parse@1.0.4 /tmp/staged/app/node_modules/jade/node_modules/transformers/node_modules/css/node_modules/css-parse
2016-03-15T11:36:38.13-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        uglify-js@2.2.5 /tmp/staged/app/node_modules/jade/node_modules/transformers/node_modules/uglify-js
2016-03-15T11:36:38.13-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        amdefine@1.0.0 /tmp/staged/app/node_modules/jade/node_modules/transformers/node_modules/uglify-js/node_modules/source-map/node_modules/amdefine
2016-03-15T11:36:38.13-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        optimist@0.3.7 /tmp/staged/app/node_modules/jade/node_modules/transformers/node_modules/uglify-js/node_modules/optimist
2016-03-15T11:36:38.13-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        wordwrap@0.0.3 /tmp/staged/app/node_modules/jade/node_modules/transformers/node_modules/uglify-js/node_modules/optimist/node_modules/wordwrap
2016-03-15T11:36:38.13-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        uglify-js@2.6.2 /tmp/staged/app/node_modules/jade/node_modules/uglify-js
2016-03-15T11:36:38.13-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        async@0.2.10 /tmp/staged/app/node_modules/jade/node_modules/uglify-js/node_modules/async
2016-03-15T11:36:38.13-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        source-map@0.5.3 /tmp/staged/app/node_modules/jade/node_modules/uglify-js/node_modules/source-map
2016-03-15T11:36:38.13-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        uglify-to-browserify@1.0.2 /tmp/staged/app/node_modules/jade/node_modules/uglify-js/node_modules/uglify-to-browserify
2016-03-15T11:36:38.14-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        yargs@3.10.0 /tmp/staged/app/node_modules/jade/node_modules/uglify-js/node_modules/yargs
2016-03-15T11:36:38.14-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        camelcase@1.2.1 /tmp/staged/app/node_modules/jade/node_modules/uglify-js/node_modules/yargs/node_modules/camelcase
2016-03-15T11:36:38.14-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        cliui@2.1.0 /tmp/staged/app/node_modules/jade/node_modules/uglify-js/node_modules/yargs/node_modules/cliui
2016-03-15T11:36:38.14-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        center-align@0.1.3 /tmp/staged/app/node_modules/jade/node_modules/uglify-js/node_modules/yargs/node_modules/cliui/node_modules/center-align
2016-03-15T11:36:38.14-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        align-text@0.1.4 /tmp/staged/app/node_modules/jade/node_modules/uglify-js/node_modules/yargs/node_modules/cliui/node_modules/center-align/node_modules/align-text
2016-03-15T11:36:38.14-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        kind-of@3.0.2 /tmp/staged/app/node_modules/jade/node_modules/uglify-js/node_modules/yargs/node_modules/cliui/node_modules/center-align/node_modules/align-text/node_modules/kind-of
2016-03-15T11:36:38.14-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        is-buffer@1.1.3 /tmp/staged/app/node_modules/jade/node_modules/uglify-js/node_modules/yargs/node_modules/cliui/node_modules/center-align/node_modules/align-text/node_modules/kind-of/node_modules/is-buffer
2016-03-15T11:36:38.14-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        longest@1.0.1 /tmp/staged/app/node_modules/jade/node_modules/uglify-js/node_modules/yargs/node_modules/cliui/node_modules/center-align/node_modules/align-text/node_modules/longest
2016-03-15T11:36:38.14-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        repeat-string@1.5.4 /tmp/staged/app/node_modules/jade/node_modules/uglify-js/node_modules/yargs/node_modules/cliui/node_modules/center-align/node_modules/align-text/node_modules/repeat-string
2016-03-15T11:36:38.14-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        lazy-cache@1.0.3 /tmp/staged/app/node_modules/jade/node_modules/uglify-js/node_modules/yargs/node_modules/cliui/node_modules/center-align/node_modules/lazy-cache
2016-03-15T11:36:38.14-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        right-align@0.1.3 /tmp/staged/app/node_modules/jade/node_modules/uglify-js/node_modules/yargs/node_modules/cliui/node_modules/right-align
2016-03-15T11:36:38.14-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        align-text@0.1.4 /tmp/staged/app/node_modules/jade/node_modules/uglify-js/node_modules/yargs/node_modules/cliui/node_modules/right-align/node_modules/align-text
2016-03-15T11:36:38.14-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        kind-of@3.0.2 /tmp/staged/app/node_modules/jade/node_modules/uglify-js/node_modules/yargs/node_modules/cliui/node_modules/right-align/node_modules/align-text/node_modules/kind-of
2016-03-15T11:36:38.14-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        is-buffer@1.1.3 /tmp/staged/app/node_modules/jade/node_modules/uglify-js/node_modules/yargs/node_modules/cliui/node_modules/right-align/node_modules/align-text/node_modules/kind-of/node_modules/is-buffer
2016-03-15T11:36:38.14-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        longest@1.0.1 /tmp/staged/app/node_modules/jade/node_modules/uglify-js/node_modules/yargs/node_modules/cliui/node_modules/right-align/node_modules/align-text/node_modules/longest
2016-03-15T11:36:38.14-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        repeat-string@1.5.4 /tmp/staged/app/node_modules/jade/node_modules/uglify-js/node_modules/yargs/node_modules/cliui/node_modules/right-align/node_modules/align-text/node_modules/repeat-string
2016-03-15T11:36:38.14-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        wordwrap@0.0.2 /tmp/staged/app/node_modules/jade/node_modules/uglify-js/node_modules/yargs/node_modules/cliui/node_modules/wordwrap
2016-03-15T11:36:38.14-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        decamelize@1.2.0 /tmp/staged/app/node_modules/jade/node_modules/uglify-js/node_modules/yargs/node_modules/decamelize
2016-03-15T11:36:38.14-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        window-size@0.1.0 /tmp/staged/app/node_modules/jade/node_modules/uglify-js/node_modules/yargs/node_modules/window-size
2016-03-15T11:36:38.15-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        void-elements@2.0.1 /tmp/staged/app/node_modules/jade/node_modules/void-elements
2016-03-15T11:36:38.15-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        with@4.0.3 /tmp/staged/app/node_modules/jade/node_modules/with
2016-03-15T11:36:38.15-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        acorn@1.2.2 /tmp/staged/app/node_modules/jade/node_modules/with/node_modules/acorn
2016-03-15T11:36:38.15-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        acorn-globals@1.0.9 /tmp/staged/app/node_modules/jade/node_modules/with/node_modules/acorn-globals
2016-03-15T11:36:38.15-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        acorn@2.7.0 /tmp/staged/app/node_modules/jade/node_modules/with/node_modules/acorn-globals/node_modules/acorn
2016-03-15T11:36:38.15-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        Installing any new modules (package.json)
2016-03-15T11:36:41.37-0400 [STG/0]      OUT -----> Installing App Management
2016-03-15T11:36:41.40-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        WARN: App Management cannot be installed because the start script cannot be found.
2016-03-15T11:36:41.40-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        To install App Management utilities, specify your 'node' start script in 'package.json' or 'Procfile'.
2016-03-15T11:36:41.40-0400 [STG/0]      OUT -----> Caching build
2016-03-15T11:36:41.42-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        Clearing previous node cache
2016-03-15T11:36:41.46-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        Saving 2 cacheDirectories (default):
2016-03-15T11:36:41.46-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        - node_modules
2016-03-15T11:36:44.28-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        - bower_components (nothing to cache)
2016-03-15T11:36:44.58-0400 [STG/0]      OUT -----> Build succeeded!
2016-03-15T11:36:45.47-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        ├── @bigfunger/decompress-zip@0.2.0-stripfix2 extraneous
2016-03-15T11:36:45.47-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        ├── @spalger/angular-bootstrap@0.12.1 extraneous
2016-03-15T11:36:45.47-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        ├── @spalger/filesaver@1.1.2 extraneous
2016-03-15T11:36:45.47-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        ├── @spalger/leaflet-draw@0.2.3 extraneous
2016-03-15T11:36:45.47-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        ├── @spalger/leaflet-heat@0.1.3 extraneous
2016-03-15T11:36:45.47-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        ├── @spalger/numeral@2.0.0 extraneous
2016-03-15T11:36:45.47-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        ├── @spalger/test-subj-selector@0.2.1 extraneous
2016-03-15T11:36:45.47-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        ├── @spalger/ui-ace@0.2.3 extraneous
2016-03-15T11:36:45.47-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        ├── angular@1.4.7 extraneous
2016-03-15T11:36:45.47-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        ├── angular-bootstrap-colorpicker@3.0.19 extraneous
2016-03-15T11:36:45.47-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        ├── angular-elastic@2.5.0 extraneous
2016-03-15T11:36:45.47-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        ├── angular-route@1.4.7 extraneous
2016-03-15T11:36:45.47-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        ├── ansicolors@0.3.2 extraneous
2016-03-15T11:36:45.47-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        ├── autoprefixer@5.1.1 extraneous
2016-03-15T11:36:45.47-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        ├── autoprefixer-loader@2.0.0 extraneous
2016-03-15T11:36:45.47-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        ├── babel@5.8.23 extraneous
2016-03-15T11:36:45.47-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        ├── babel-core@5.8.23 extraneous
2016-03-15T11:36:45.47-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        ├── babel-loader@5.3.2 extraneous
2016-03-15T11:36:45.47-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        ├── babel-runtime@5.8.20 extraneous
2016-03-15T11:36:45.47-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        ├── bluebird@2.9.34 extraneous
2016-03-15T11:36:45.47-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        ├── boom@2.8.0 extraneous
2016-03-15T11:36:45.47-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        ├── bootstrap@3.3.5 extraneous
2016-03-15T11:36:45.47-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        ├── brace@0.5.1 extraneous
2016-03-15T11:36:45.47-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        ├── bunyan@1.7.1 extraneous
2016-03-15T11:36:45.47-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        ├── caniuse-db@1.0.30000265 extraneous
2016-03-15T11:36:45.47-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        ├── chalk@1.1.0 extraneous
2016-03-15T11:36:45.47-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        ├── clipboard@1.5.5 extraneous
2016-03-15T11:36:45.47-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        ├── commander@2.8.1 extraneous
2016-03-15T11:36:45.47-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        ├── css-loader@0.17.0 extraneous
2016-03-15T11:36:45.47-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        ├── d3@3.5.6 extraneous
2016-03-15T11:36:45.47-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        ├── elasticsearch@8.0.1 extraneous
2016-03-15T11:36:45.47-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        ├── elasticsearch-browser@8.0.1 extraneous
2016-03-15T11:36:45.47-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        ├── expiry-js@0.1.7 extraneous
2016-03-15T11:36:45.48-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        ├── exports-loader@0.6.2 extraneous
2016-03-15T11:36:45.48-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        ├── expose-loader@0.7.0 extraneous
2016-03-15T11:36:45.48-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        ├── extract-text-webpack-plugin@0.8.2 extraneous
2016-03-15T11:36:45.48-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        ├── file-loader@0.8.4 extraneous
2016-03-15T11:36:45.48-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        ├── font-awesome@4.4.0 extraneous
2016-03-15T11:36:45.48-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        ├── glob@4.5.3 invalid extraneous
2016-03-15T11:36:45.48-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        ├── good@6.3.0 extraneous
2016-03-15T11:36:45.48-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        ├── good-squeeze@2.1.0 extraneous
2016-03-15T11:36:45.48-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        ├── gridster@0.5.6 extraneous
2016-03-15T11:36:45.48-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        ├── hapi@8.8.1 extraneous
2016-03-15T11:36:45.48-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        ├── har-validator@1.8.0 extraneous
2016-03-15T11:36:45.48-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        ├── imports-loader@0.6.4 extraneous
2016-03-15T11:36:45.48-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        ├── jade@1.11.0 extraneous
2016-03-15T11:36:45.48-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        ├── jade-loader@0.7.1 extraneous
2016-03-15T11:36:45.48-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        ├── joi@6.6.1 extraneous
2016-03-15T11:36:45.48-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        ├── jquery@2.1.4 extraneous
2016-03-15T11:36:45.48-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        ├── js-yaml@3.4.1 extraneous
2016-03-15T11:36:45.48-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        ├── json-loader@0.5.3 extraneous
2016-03-15T11:36:45.48-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        ├── json-stringify-safe@5.0.1 extraneous
2016-03-15T11:36:45.48-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        ├── json5@0.4.0 extraneous
2016-03-15T11:36:45.48-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        ├── jstimezonedetect@1.0.5 extraneous
2016-03-15T11:36:45.48-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        ├── leaflet@0.7.5 extraneous
2016-03-15T11:36:45.48-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        ├── less@2.5.1 extraneous
2016-03-15T11:36:45.48-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        ├── less-loader@2.2.0 extraneous
2016-03-15T11:36:45.48-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        ├── loader-utils@0.2.11 extraneous
2016-03-15T11:36:45.48-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        ├── lodash@3.10.1 extraneous
2016-03-15T11:36:45.48-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        ├── marked@0.3.3 extraneous
2016-03-15T11:36:45.48-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        ├── micromatch@2.2.0 extraneous
2016-03-15T11:36:45.48-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        ├── minimatch@2.0.10 extraneous
2016-03-15T11:36:45.48-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        ├── mkdirp@0.5.1 extraneous
2016-03-15T11:36:45.48-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        ├── moment@2.10.6 extraneous
2016-03-15T11:36:45.48-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        ├── moment-timezone@0.4.1 extraneous
2016-03-15T11:36:45.48-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        ├── postcss-minify-selectors@1.4.6 extraneous
2016-03-15T11:36:45.48-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        ├── postcss-normalize-url@2.1.1 extraneous
2016-03-15T11:36:45.48-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        ├── postcss-reduce-idents@1.0.2 extraneous
2016-03-15T11:36:45.48-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        ├── postcss-single-charset@0.3.0 extraneous
2016-03-15T11:36:45.48-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        ├── postcss-unique-selectors@1.0.0 extraneous
2016-03-15T11:36:45.48-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        ├── raw-loader@0.5.1 extraneous
2016-03-15T11:36:45.48-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        ├── regenerator@0.8.36 extraneous
2016-03-15T11:36:45.48-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        ├── request@2.61.0 extraneous
2016-03-15T11:36:45.48-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        ├── requirefrom@0.2.0 extraneous
2016-03-15T11:36:45.48-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        ├── rimraf@2.4.3 extraneous
2016-03-15T11:36:45.48-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        ├── rjs-repack-loader@1.0.6 extraneous
2016-03-15T11:36:45.48-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        ├── script-loader@0.6.1 extraneous
2016-03-15T11:36:45.48-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        ├── semver@4.3.6 extraneous
2016-03-15T11:36:45.48-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        ├── style-loader@0.12.3 extraneous
2016-03-15T11:36:45.49-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        ├── tar@2.2.0 extraneous
2016-03-15T11:36:45.49-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        ├── url-loader@0.5.6 extraneous
2016-03-15T11:36:45.49-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        ├── webpack@1.12.1 extraneous
2016-03-15T11:36:45.49-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        ├── webpack-directory-name-as-main@1.0.0 extraneous
2016-03-15T11:36:45.49-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        ├── whatwg-fetch@0.9.0 extraneous
2016-03-15T11:36:45.49-0400 [STG/0]      OUT        └── wreck@6.2.0 extraneous
2016-03-15T11:36:45.55-0400 [STG/0]      ERR     
2016-03-15T11:36:54.58-0400 [STG/1]      OUT -----> Uploading droplet (36M)
2016-03-15T11:37:03.85-0400 [DEA/1]      OUT Starting app instance (index 0) with guid 6ca26e72-d314-4659-8968-1824d40924e9
2016-03-15T11:37:11.22-0400 [App/0]      ERR     npm ERR! Linux 3.19.0-33-generic
2016-03-15T11:37:11.22-0400 [App/0]      ERR npm ERR! argv "/home/vcap/app/vendor/node/bin/node" "/home/vcap/app/vendor/node/bin/npm" "start"
2016-03-15T11:37:11.22-0400 [App/0]      ERR npm ERR! node v4.3.2
2016-03-15T11:37:11.22-0400 [App/0]      ERR npm ERR! npm  v2.14.12
2016-03-15T11:37:11.22-0400 [App/0]      ERR npm ERR! missing script: start
2016-03-15T11:37:11.22-0400 [App/0]      ERR npm ERR! 
2016-03-15T11:37:11.22-0400 [App/0]      ERR npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
2016-03-15T11:37:11.22-0400 [App/0]      ERR npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
2016-03-15T11:37:11.23-0400 [App/0]      ERR npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
2016-03-15T11:37:11.23-0400 [App/0]      ERR npm ERR!     /home/vcap/app/npm-debug.log
2016-03-15T11:37:11.24-0400 [App/0]      OUT     
2016-03-15T11:37:11.32-0400 [DEA/1]      ERR Instance (index 0) failed to start accepting connections
2016-03-15T11:37:11.34-0400 [API/0]      OUT App instance exited with guid 6ca26e72-d314-4659-8968-1824d40924e9 payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>"6ca26e72-d314-4659-8968-1824d40924e9", "version"=>"2bbb4be0-2d32-42ed-a45f-ae0e3faddf08", "instance"=>"b463e8b29e7a4bf08ba0c0dcc207bde6", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>1, "exit_description"=>"failed to accept connections within health check timeout", "crash_timestamp"=>1458056231}
2016-03-15T11:37:11.34-0400 [API/1]      OUT App instance exited with guid 6ca26e72-d314-4659-8968-1824d40924e9 payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>"6ca26e72-d314-4659-8968-1824d40924e9", "version"=>"2bbb4be0-2d32-42ed-a45f-ae0e3faddf08", "instance"=>"b463e8b29e7a4bf08ba0c0dcc207bde6", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>1, "exit_description"=>"failed to accept connections within health check timeout", "crash_timestamp"=>1458056231}
2016-03-15T11:38:07.72-0400 [DEA/4]      OUT Starting app instance (index 0) with guid 6ca26e72-d314-4659-8968-1824d40924e9
2016-03-15T11:38:14.10-0400 [App/0]      ERR     npm ERR! Linux 3.19.0-33-generic
2016-03-15T11:38:14.10-0400 [App/0]      ERR npm ERR! argv "/home/vcap/app/vendor/node/bin/node" "/home/vcap/app/vendor/node/bin/npm" "start"
2016-03-15T11:38:14.10-0400 [App/0]      ERR npm ERR! node v4.3.2
2016-03-15T11:38:14.10-0400 [App/0]      ERR npm ERR! npm  v2.14.12
2016-03-15T11:38:14.10-0400 [App/0]      ERR npm ERR! missing script: start
2016-03-15T11:38:14.10-0400 [App/0]      ERR npm ERR! 
2016-03-15T11:38:14.10-0400 [App/0]      ERR npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
2016-03-15T11:38:14.10-0400 [App/0]      ERR npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
2016-03-15T11:38:14.11-0400 [App/0]      ERR npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
2016-03-15T11:38:14.11-0400 [App/0]      ERR npm ERR!     /home/vcap/app/npm-debug.log
2016-03-15T11:38:14.12-0400 [App/0]      OUT     
2016-03-15T11:38:14.19-0400 [DEA/4]      ERR Instance (index 0) failed to start accepting connections
2016-03-15T11:38:14.24-0400 [API/1]      OUT App instance exited with guid 6ca26e72-d314-4659-8968-1824d40924e9 payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>"6ca26e72-d314-4659-8968-1824d40924e9", "version"=>"2bbb4be0-2d32-42ed-a45f-ae0e3faddf08", "instance"=>"b20c768699f247b2a4db78fe18fa38ad", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>1, "exit_description"=>"failed to accept connections within health check timeout", "crash_timestamp"=>1458056294}
2016-03-15T11:38:14.24-0400 [API/1]      OUT App instance exited with guid 6ca26e72-d314-4659-8968-1824d40924e9 payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>"6ca26e72-d314-4659-8968-1824d40924e9", "version"=>"2bbb4be0-2d32-42ed-a45f-ae0e3faddf08", "instance"=>"b20c768699f247b2a4db78fe18fa38ad", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>1, "exit_description"=>"failed to accept connections within health check timeout", "crash_timestamp"=>1458056294}
2016-03-15T11:39:07.74-0400 [DEA/6]      OUT Starting app instance (index 0) with guid 6ca26e72-d314-4659-8968-1824d40924e9
2016-03-15T11:39:14.39-0400 [App/0]      ERR     npm ERR! Linux 3.19.0-33-generic
2016-03-15T11:39:14.39-0400 [App/0]      ERR npm ERR! argv "/home/vcap/app/vendor/node/bin/node" "/home/vcap/app/vendor/node/bin/npm" "start"
2016-03-15T11:39:14.39-0400 [App/0]      ERR npm ERR! node v4.3.2
2016-03-15T11:39:14.39-0400 [App/0]      ERR npm ERR! npm  v2.14.12
2016-03-15T11:39:14.39-0400 [App/0]      ERR npm ERR! missing script: start
2016-03-15T11:39:14.39-0400 [App/0]      ERR npm ERR! 
2016-03-15T11:39:14.39-0400 [App/0]      ERR npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
2016-03-15T11:39:14.39-0400 [App/0]      ERR npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
2016-03-15T11:39:14.40-0400 [App/0]      ERR npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
2016-03-15T11:39:14.40-0400 [App/0]      ERR npm ERR!     /home/vcap/app/npm-debug.log
2016-03-15T11:39:14.41-0400 [App/0]      OUT     
2016-03-15T11:39:14.47-0400 [DEA/6]      ERR Instance (index 0) failed to start accepting connections
2016-03-15T11:39:14.49-0400 [API/1]      OUT App instance exited with guid 6ca26e72-d314-4659-8968-1824d40924e9 payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>"6ca26e72-d314-4659-8968-1824d40924e9", "version"=>"2bbb4be0-2d32-42ed-a45f-ae0e3faddf08", "instance"=>"3cd5385706044dd1afe215b2fe7a3185", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>1, "exit_description"=>"failed to accept connections within health check timeout", "crash_timestamp"=>1458056354}
2016-03-15T11:39:14.49-0400 [API/0]      OUT App instance exited with guid 6ca26e72-d314-4659-8968-1824d40924e9 payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>"6ca26e72-d314-4659-8968-1824d40924e9", "version"=>"2bbb4be0-2d32-42ed-a45f-ae0e3faddf08", "instance"=>"3cd5385706044dd1afe215b2fe7a3185", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>1, "exit_description"=>"failed to accept connections within health check timeout", "crash_timestamp"=>1458056354}
2016-03-15T11:40:07.72-0400 [DEA/0]      OUT Starting app instance (index 0) with guid 6ca26e72-d314-4659-8968-1824d40924e9
2016-03-15T11:40:13.34-0400 [App/0]      ERR     npm ERR! Linux 3.19.0-33-generic
2016-03-15T11:40:13.34-0400 [App/0]      ERR npm ERR! argv "/home/vcap/app/vendor/node/bin/node" "/home/vcap/app/vendor/node/bin/npm" "start"
2016-03-15T11:40:13.34-0400 [App/0]      ERR npm ERR! node v4.3.2
2016-03-15T11:40:13.35-0400 [App/0]      ERR npm ERR! npm  v2.14.12
2016-03-15T11:40:13.35-0400 [App/0]      ERR npm ERR! missing script: start
2016-03-15T11:40:13.35-0400 [App/0]      ERR npm ERR! 
2016-03-15T11:40:13.35-0400 [App/0]      ERR npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
2016-03-15T11:40:13.35-0400 [App/0]      ERR npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
2016-03-15T11:40:13.36-0400 [App/0]      ERR npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
2016-03-15T11:40:13.36-0400 [App/0]      ERR npm ERR!     /home/vcap/app/npm-debug.log
2016-03-15T11:40:13.37-0400 [App/0]      OUT     
2016-03-15T11:40:13.44-0400 [DEA/0]      ERR Instance (index 0) failed to start accepting connections
2016-03-15T11:40:13.45-0400 [API/1]      OUT App instance exited with guid 6ca26e72-d314-4659-8968-1824d40924e9 payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>"6ca26e72-d314-4659-8968-1824d40924e9", "version"=>"2bbb4be0-2d32-42ed-a45f-ae0e3faddf08", "instance"=>"e9ee582dd49c4a28bc2907afbc48c37b", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>1, "exit_description"=>"failed to accept connections within health check timeout", "crash_timestamp"=>1458056413}
2016-03-15T11:40:13.45-0400 [API/1]      OUT App instance exited with guid 6ca26e72-d314-4659-8968-1824d40924e9 payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>"6ca26e72-d314-4659-8968-1824d40924e9", "version"=>"2bbb4be0-2d32-42ed-a45f-ae0e3faddf08", "instance"=>"e9ee582dd49c4a28bc2907afbc48c37b", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>1, "exit_description"=>"failed to accept connections within health check timeout", "crash_timestamp"=>1458056413}
```

Comment: Which error messages do you get? I haven't done myself but perhaps reading the error message we can help...

Comment: in cf logs, i can see `"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>1, "exit_description"=>"failed to accept connections within health check timeout", "crash_timestamp"=>1458060524}`

Comment: i have also added the entire error stacktrace

Comment: Looks like it is running npm start rather than the command you set in the manifest.yml and so is failing as you have no start script in your package.json. Maybe add the start script in your package.json rather than use the command property in the manifest.yml.

Comment: thanks but there is no `bin/kibana.js` in Kibana 4.4.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally figured it out. all you have to do is

create `manifest.yml` next to `package.json`

```
---
applications:
- name: %name_of_app%
  memory: 512M
  host: %name_of_app%
  domain: %name_of_domain%
```

create a `Procfile` next to `package.json`

```
web: bin/kibana --port $PORT
```

and we are done :)